# How to work with both (landscape and portrait) orientation?

Tags: android-layout

I want to take care for both orientation for my application. So should i need to design two layouts (one for portrait and one for landscape).. ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to have 2 different UI arrangements (which is likely).